# Data fetch and insert in SQL Server Compact Edition database using VB.net

Tags: sql-server-ce, vb.net-2010

I am new to VB.net and creating an application so that user needs login username and password.

I am using a SQL Server Compact Edition database.

This is my code which works perfect:-

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

Public Class frm_edit_patient
    Dim con As New SqlCeConnection
    Try
        Dim SQLquery As String
        Dim da As SqlCeDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim myConString As String = My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString
        con.ConnectionString = myConString
        MsgBox("Database is now open")
        MessageBox.Show("connected")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The above code works fine and shows me `connected`

However when I add this piece of code

```
        SQLquery = "SELECT id FROM user where username=John Doe"
        da = New SqlCeDataAdapter(SQLquery, con)
        da = New SqlCeDataAdapter(SQLquery, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "db1")
```

It gives me this exception error:-
[image]

What does it mean? how to get the userid of that particular person?

Also if i just put the insert query in `SQLquery`, will it work? As i have been doing this by watching few video tutorials, but further they don't have tutorials on this, also my book does not explains anything about Compact databases and as i am so far with this application dont want to switch...

Comment: I have done this: `where username = 'John Doe'` but error is still the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your username between single quotes and **user** is a [reserved word in Sql Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173340.aspx).
You need to enclose it in square brackets

```
SQLquery = "SELECT id FROM [user] where username='John Doe'"
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Do you have the square brackets around user?

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked :) A last question how i can display that data...?

Comment: You can use your DataSet and extract the info from the ds.Tables(0).Rows(0) and display it in a grid or in a textbox

Answer (score 3):

Add single quotes around your query.

```
SQLquery = "SELECT id FROM user where username='John Doe'"
```

Comment: Do you have `con.open()` anywhere?

Comment: Oh yes offcource i have it just above my `SQLquery` as `con.open()`

Comment: Try altering your code to follow this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedataadapter(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your SQL statement. Strings must be delimited using single quotes e.g.

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = 'John Doe'
```